# What happens when a php file (which is currently in use) is uploaded to server?

Tags: php, file-upload, ftp

**Case:**
I have a PHP script that is currently being executed by many users.
This script takes some time to complete (say, fetch data from browser, process it, update database etc.)

Now I modified the script and I upload it to the server using a FTP client.
The FTP client happily uploads it and says uploaded.

---

**Now what really happened here?**
When I uploaded the modified script, what happened to current executions?

The possibilities I came up with are:

**1)** All the current executions are screwed.
   The executions stopped when the new script was uploaded.
   If this is the case (which I pray is not) how can a script be uploaded to the server without affecting the current executions?

**2)** The current executions are completed with the old script. When a new request comes, it's processed with the new modified script.

**3)** Something else?

Comment: Is APC enabled on your server or not?

Comment: @Burhan what do you mean restart apache? For every file modifications (say index.php etc.) you are suggesting restart apache?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's say you have `index.php` which does some intensive calculations, taking a decent amount of time, and then makes a call to `process.php`

A visitor comes to your website and loads up `index.php`. This is loaded into memory by your web server software (Apache, nginx, IIS etc) and served to your visitor. While your visitor is running those calculations on `index.php` you decide to upload updated versions of both `index.php` and `process.php`. At this point in time your visitor will keep running the **old** version of `index.php` and they will not see the new version until they refresh the page.

They will however see the new version of `process.php` after the old version of `index.php`makes a call to it. This is because the server reads whatever file is called, loads it up into memory and serves it to the user creating a session between the server and the user. If the user attempted to get process.php or index.php while it was partially uploaded they will get an error.

Comment: thanks a lot for the reply. "If the user attempted to get process.php or index.php while it was partially uploaded they will get an error." what do you mean partially uploaded? The file will be available only after the whole file is uploaded. right?

Comment: Let's take the case of a file uploading script. The user selects the file & click upload. The target file is upload.php. this file processes the file, update the database etc. While processing the file  I uploaded a new version of upload.php. Now what happens to the current running process?

Comment: If the server has already started processing the user request to upload the file via upload.php and then you upload a new version of upload.php, there will be no effect on users who have already started the file upload process if you upload a new version. By partially uploaded I meant that some server configurations allow you to access a file that is not 100% complete uploading.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I didn't know about partial upload case. Could you tell more about the server configurations that leads to this (i'm using apache server). If possible can you add those to the answer. I guess, someone out there like me might not know about this.

Comment: Not sure...I've only seen this behavior on shared hosting. For the countless times I've installed Apache or IIS I've never had an issue with this using the default settings.

Answer (score 1):

If you have APC on your server the script will be executed with the old code until you restart apache.

If not, well, you simply don't know, but I vote for solution number **2**: the script should be "in memory" when executed, then discarded upon execution end.

Comment: Even if APC is enabled, the entire file (eg: index.php) is not always cached in APC no?

Comment: APC is an opcode cache. So it saves the "compiled" bytecode of the file at the first hit of it into the webserver, until the configured TTL ends.

Comment: Ok. lets take the case where APC is not enabled